# Creating HMAC for PHP encryption

Tags: php, encryption

I've just been looking at adding a HMAC to PHP mcrypt encryption.

Is this simply hashing the encrypted data with hash_hmac using the encryption key and appending it to the encrypted data? Then on decryption you split off the HMAC, hash_hmac the rest of the data with the key again and check it matches the HMAC.

I'm confused because in this SO question *[When authenticating ciphertexts, what should be HMACed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20464/when-authenticating-ciphertexts-what-should-be-hmaced#answers)* it says:

> you have to include in the HMAC input everything that impacts the decryption process, i.e. not only the encryption result per se, but also the IV which was used for that encryption, and, if the overall protocol supports algorithm agility, you should also input the specification of the encryption algorithm (otherwise, an attacker could alter the header of your message to replace the tag which says "AES-256" with the tag which says "AES-128" and you would unknowingly decrypt with the wrong algorithm).

Is this so? If this is true, why isn't using hash_hmac on just the encrypted data enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Yes

**Long Answer**:

[HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) is Hash-based message authentication code.  You should HMAC anything which you want to authenticate, or in other words, anything which you want to protect against being modified.

Although [the RFC standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition_.28from_RFC_2104.29) is more complicated, it may make sense to think of HMAC as a salted hash.

> e.g. hmac(message, key) = hash(message + key)

1. You can **only** recreate the same hmac with an **identical message and key**.
2. You **can't** recreate the same hmac if the key is identical but the message differs.
3. You **can't** recreate the same hmac if the message is identical but the key differs.

An attacker (*who doesn't have the HMAC key*) cannot modify part of the HMAC message without invalidating the existing HMAC.  It really does depend on your data format and your usage of that data to determine what should be included in the HMAC message and HMAC key.  But assuming you are using the HMAC to authenticate the decryption, then **you should always include in the HMAC message anything that the decryption depends on**.  The symmetric key is typically used as the HMAC key.

In your quote, the poster says the IV and the algorithm should also be hashed.  Consider a file/database format consisting of

> ALGORITHM + IV + CIPHERTEXT + HMAC

If you only HMAC the ciphertext, an attacker would be able to modify the algorithm or IV (corrupting the file) without affecting the validity of the HMAC.  This is bad because you can end up with a corrupted encrypted file with a valid HMAC.  Decryption will proceed as normal because your software will think everything is ok.  The result is a totally garbled decryption, but the point is that your software is broken because it returned the wrong output when decrypting and didn't give any errors.  This can be classed as a **'security risk'** if your application tries to do something with that erroneous data because it assumes it is correct.  It is **not** a security risk in the sense that it makes the underlying encryption weaker or easier to crack.  HMAC and symmetric encryption are two totally different technologies doing different things.  The point of using a HMAC is that you can assume that the decryption layer is returning data which is 100% correct.

In the above example the ALGORITHM is a dynamic piece of data which I used to explain "*algorithm agility*" in the OPs quote.  It defines what encryption algorithm was used.  The point is that it is **dynamic** so it needs to be read from somewhere rather than hardcoded.  This fact makes it **a dependency** of the decryption so it **should be included in the HMAC message**.  However, if you always use some **static** algorithm then it should be assumed by (hardcoded in to) your decryption code and there is no need to store this data anyway.  There is no need to include static data in the HMAC message because it has no affect on the decryption.

An example of a file format which uses a static algorithm is [the open source AES-256 Crypt File Format](https://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html).  The algorithm is consistent and so it is always assumed.  It actually uses 2 HMACs for speed reasons. 1 to authenticate the IV and keys, and the 2nd to authenticate the encrypted data part.

Comment: It can still be check if the decryption was successful if the encryption library checks all bytes of the padding. If there is even one error in the padding, it can throw an exception or something like that. An HMAC prevents you from doing the decryption if it is corrupted.

Comment: Depending on the padding used, authentication by checking for valid padding is nearly always less reliable than using a hmac. It might randomly create a valid padding by accident even with a bad decryption.

Comment: “This is bad because you can end up with a corrupted encrypted file with a valid HMAC.” This doesn't pose any security risk though, does it?

Comment: Also, is there a case to HMAC the other information such as the algorithm used to hash password (e.g. 'pbkdf2') or the password's salt? Or is HMACing ALGORITHM + IV + ENCRYPTED DATA enough? I don't want to HMAC data I don't need to. Finally, is the 'ALGORITHM' just an arbitrary text representation of of the mcrypt cipher mode used? E.g. could be 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'

Comment: How you use your encryption/decryption layer is what is important here.  Generally, assumptions are bad in software.  If your application code makes the assumption that the decryption was successful and acts on the erroneous data, it could be harmless or it could be very bad.  Whether it is a "security risk" depends on your definition, but it certainly would be classed as a problem which exists at the encryption/decryption layer.  But no, it is not a security risk which makes it easier to crack the underlying encryption if that's what you're asking.

Comment: ALGORITHM just represents some algorithm and was used as an example to detail that issue.  I was not referring to some magic file format which should be used for storing encrypted files.  Please see my AES Crypt link if you are looking for a file format.

Comment: I thought so re security. So really if a HMAC was done once on just encrypted data + IV that wouldn't lead to any issues so long as your other variables relating to hashing and encryption are constant? I'm storing IV, salt and encrypted data in separate DB fields so, although your link was interesting, I am not trying to keep them in an AES file.

Comment: Yes. You only need to include the data which you want to authenticate within the HMAC contents.  If you always use the same method of encryption and decryption then there is no need to authenticate this since it is assumed.  If you are familar with salts and hashing, it might be a good idea to think of HMAC as just a salted hash of contents where the key is the salt.  HMAC = hash(key + contents).  You can never find out the key from the hmac, and you need the key to be the same and the contents to be the same to end up with the same result.

Comment: Thanks, Phil_1984_. Do you want to include that in your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: No problem.  I have tried to incorporate everything we discussed here. Thanks